# Find all continuous functions with the following properties.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I find all continuous functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$ \int_{a}^x f(t) dt = \int_{x}^b f(t) dt$$ ,
for all $x \in (a,b)$

This problem is from old qualifyings of real analysis  , it does not look too bad but still I struggled quit a good time. I tried to define some functions to work out but non of them did the job.

Any little hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Taking a derivative might help.

Comment: do not we need $f$ to be differentiable?

Comment: Derivative of the integral <--> Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: @mp100 Not to differentiate $F\colon x\mapsto =\int_a^x f$, which is differentiable (even $C^1$).

Comment: that is correct

Comment: The only function satisfying that requirement I got is a zero function. I do not think that we can have such non zero function for arbitrary $x$.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int_a^x = \int_a^b - \int_x^b = \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

If a = b, then any function works.
If a < b, then f is a constant function equal to 0. Really, for any c < d from [a, b] consider three integrals:

I1 from a to c,
I2 from c to d,
I3 from d to b.

Obviously I1 + I2 = I3 and I1 = I2 + I3 by the property of f. This means I2 is 0. Because it is true for any c, d, integral from a to x is always 0 for any x from [a, b]. Taking its derivative by x becomes 0, and it is also f.